# Is there a geometric proof of $\frac1r = \frac{1}{h_a} + \frac{1}{h_b} + \frac{1}{h_c}$ in a given triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, alternative-proof, proof-without-words

Can anyone provide a geometric proof of $\frac1r = \frac{1}{h_a} + \frac{1}{h_b} + \frac{1}{h_c}$ in a given triangle, if there is one? Here, $h_i$ refers to the distance from the side $i$ to the opposite vertex, and $r$ is the inradius. I get the proof of the formula but I would like to get an intuitive understanding of it.

Comment: Area $\Delta = \frac12 r(a+b+c)$ implies $\frac1r = \frac{a}{2\Delta} + \frac{b}{2\Delta} + \frac{c}{2\Delta} = \cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$2A=ah_a=bh_b=ch_c$$ and $$A=sr$$ we get
$$\frac{s}{A}=\frac{a}{2A}+\frac{b}{2A}+\frac{c}{2A}$$ which is true, after cancelling the $$A$$ (area)